# JSON backward compatibility read/write

Tags: json, scala, playframework, backwards-compatibility

I am looking for help in reading/writing of JSON string in my DB in a backward compatible way.
The JSON names and objects are in case class FeatureList.

Old format:

`"featureRequired":"Yes"`

New format:

`"featureRequired": {"thisfeatureRequired" :"Yes", "featureDetails": "Some text"}`

```scala
case class FeatureList (
field1 : type,
.
.
.
featureRequired: Boolean //this is field22
)
```

The Issue : The legacy code reads `featureRequired` as a string. Then converts to boolean for decision making. For my new requirement, featureRequired is an object of `{thisfeatureRequired, featureDetails}`

We use scala play library for json manipulation.

The question : For my requirement, how do I READ the new format, which is backward compatible with the old one? Will custom formatter help? Can someone give an example please.

Comment: How is you current `Reads[FeatureList]` written?

Comment: Global idea would be to have a custom `Reads` which tries to parse `featureRequired` as `JsObject` and fallback to `JsBoolean`.